# Script to report disk usage

Tags: time-limit-exceeded, file-system, linux, unix, tcsh

I am trying to see how I can speed up the below script that reports disk usage.

The timed `find` command towards the end is the problematic line that I am trying to speed up. This script is run on directories that have over 6-7TB of data and it takes 16-18hrs. However I want it to run in under 8hrs. Can someone please suggest alternate ways to modify this script?

```
# -disk_check.csh takes dir name as a mandatory argument and an options <num> or -verbose as a second argument.
#  Ex1: disk_check <dir_name> - Reports out the disk usage per user and the total disk consumption
#  Ex2: disk_check <dir_name> -verbose -Along with the above, it also lists all files by size in the given directory
#  Ex3: disk_check <dir_name> -<num> -Similar to Ex2, But here it reports out the top <num> files by size in the given directory


if ($#argv == 0) then
    echo " Error : Dir path missing"
    echo " Syntax : disk_check <dir-name> <verbose>"
    echo "          verbose gives a list of all files per individual sorted by size" 
    exit 0 
endif

set cwd = $argv[1]
if ($cwd =~ "-help") then
    echo " Error : Dir path missing"
    echo " Syntax : disk_check <dir-name> <-verbose>"
    echo "          -verbose gives a list of all files per individual sorted by size" 
    exit 0
endif

if ($#argv > 1) then
    set opt = $argv[2]
#echo "opt : $opt"
endif

if ( -d $cwd ) then

set ava = `df -h $cwd | tail -1 | awk '{print $1'}`
set tot = `df -h $cwd | tail -1 | awk '{print $2'}`
set ad = `df -h $cwd | tail -1 | awk '{print $3'}`
set pcu = `df -h $cwd | tail -1 | awk '{print $4'}`

echo ""
echo "Summary for dir ${cwd}: $tot Used (${pcu})"
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo " Total Volume $ava"
echo " Available on disk $ad "
echo " Percentage used $pcu"
echo ""
echo "Summary by User:"
printf "%sUser%15sSize%10sCount\n" ""
echo "---------------------------------------------"

# This is the command that takes a long time:
time find $cwd -type f -printf "%u %s\n" | awk '{user[$1]+=$2;count[$1]++}; END{ for( i in user) printf "%s%-13s%5s%-0.2f%s%5s%7s\n","", i, "", user[i]/1024**3,"GB", "", count[i]}'| sort -nk2 -r


if ($#argv > 1) then
    if ($opt =~ "-verbose") then
        echo "\nDetail, Sorted by size"
        printf " User%15sFile%15sSize\n" ""
        echo "---------------------------------------------------"
        find $cwd -type f -not -path '*/\.*'  -printf "%-13u | %-50p | %-10s \n" | sort -nk5 -r 
endif
```

Comment: Have you considered turning on disk quotas? Then the filesystem keeps track of the usage per user, and you can run `quota` to get a report.

Comment: Have you profiled which part of the script is taking such a long time?

Comment: @Mast The specific `find` command has already been identified as a performance problem.

Comment: @200_success That specific line is the problem, yes. It's also doing most of the heavy lifting of the script, a `find`, `sort` and `awk` call. Given the amount of data it's used on, I'm not sure `find` is the only problem here.

Comment: @Mast The time taken by awk and sort are surely insignificant compared to scanning an entire filesystem!